# How does include statement work in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

According to [this page documentatation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html), the following code should work fine:

```
<div class="paginator">
    <strong>pagina</strong>
    <!-- Loop here -->
    <a class="current "href="#">1</a>
    <!-- End loop -->
    <!-- This tag is only an example: --><a href="#">2</a>
    {% include 'pagination.html.twig' with { 
        currentFilters: { myFilter: filtervariables }, 
        currentPage: page, 
        paginationPath: "myroute", 
        lastPage: totalPages, 
        showAlwaysFirstAndLast: true 
    } only %}
</div>
```

However it returns:

`Unable to find template "pagination.html.twig" in something.html.twig at line (number).`

The page is in the same folder as the `pagination.html.twig` so I can't seem to understand what's happening. Is there anyone that can explain me what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's better to use the include function and not the tag (`{{ include('pagination.html.twig, {}) }}`), because the tag is deprecated and it will be removed at some point (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html)

Then, you have to use the full qualified path name to the template. if your `pagination.html.twig` is in in the `app/Resources/foo/bar` folder, you have to write `foo/bar/pagination.html.twig`. If it's in the `src/Bundle/FooBundle/Resources/views/bar` folder, you have to write `@Foo/bar/pagination.html.twig`

Comment: Should just return `somefolder/template.html.twig` instead of `views/somefolder/template.htm.twig`

Comment: Ah, didn't knew the tag will be deprecated, can't find a note about it at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: Hm, Actually, it is not deprecated. But it should be ;) (a tag should not output contents)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path using bundle name and view directory name etc:

```
 {{ include('AppBundle:Default:pagination.html.twig', {}) }}
```

where 'AppBundle' is a bundle name contains view with 'Default' directory having pagination.html.twig file.

Comment: AppBundle:Default:pagination.html.twig is the old way to reference a view. See my answer for the modern way

Comment: Thanks lyrixx, actually i didn't knew that is old way.